# Insert new rows into pandas dataframe depending on range of 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like:

```
ID       value1   start     end
 1         100     1        2       
 1         200     2        4
 2         50      1        1
 2         30      3        5
```

I want to fill in new rows for each value between start and end

The final df should look like this where period is each unique value between start and end

```
    ID       value1      period     
     1         100     1        
     1         100     2            
     1         200     2 
     1         200     3 
     1         200     4       
     2         50      1        
     2         30      3    
     2         30      4 
     2         30      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using for loop create the list of column with `range` , this become an [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/7964527) problem

```
df['New']=[list(range(x,y+1)) for x , y in zip(df.start,df.end)]
Yourdf=unnesting(df,['New'])
Yourdf
   New  ID  value1  start  end
0    1   1     100      1    2
0    2   1     100      1    2
1    2   1     200      2    4
1    3   1     200      2    4
1    4   1     200      2    4
2    1   2      50      1    1
3    3   2      30      3    5
3    4   2      30      3    5
3    5   2      30      3    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the below, list comprehension:

```
>>> df['period']=[','.join(map(str,range(x,y+1))) for x,y in zip(df['start'],df['end'])]
>>> df.set_index(['ID','value1','start','end']).stack().str.split(',', expand=True).stack().unstack(-2).reset_index(-1,drop=True).reset_index()
   ID  value1  start  end period
0   1     100      1    2      1
1   1     100      1    2      2
2   1     200      2    4      2
3   1     200      2    4      3
4   1     200      2    4      4
5   2      30      3    5      3
6   2      30      3    5      4
7   2      30      3    5      5
8   2      50      1    1      1
>>>
```

If you want to drop columns:

```
>>> df['period']=[','.join(map(str,range(x,y+1))) for x,y in zip(df.pop('start'),df.pop('end'))]
>>> df.set_index(['ID','value1']).stack().str.split(',', expand=True).stack().unstack(-2).reset_index(-1,drop=True).reset_index()
   ID  value1 period
0   1     100      1
1   1     100      2
2   1     200      2
3   1     200      3
4   1     200      4
5   2      30      3
6   2      30      4
7   2      30      5
8   2      50      1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make use *start* and *end* to create the new *period* column as a list of values, using the `range` built-in function.
2. Use pd.DataFrame method `explode` to transform each element of *period* on a distinct row.
3. Drop *start* and *end* columns
4. (optionally) stlyer *hide* index from output

```
(df
 .assign(period=df.apply(lambda df: list((range(df.start, df.end + 1))), axis=1))
 .explode('period')
 .drop(columns=['start', 'end'])
 .style.hide()
)

ID  value1  period
1   100     1
1   100     2
1   200     2
1   200     3
1   200     4
2   50      1
2   30      3
2   30      4
2   30      5
```